# Exception in a timer with an aync callback method

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, http, async-await

I have inherited some code where this pattern (simplified) is being used to poll a device every second and check if it has new data trough it's REST api:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

public class Class
{
    private readonly string _iotIPaddress = "123.456.789.0";
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer = null;
    private readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public Constructor()
    {
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(--secrets--);
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds);
        _timer.Elapsed += OnTimer;
    }

    private async void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _timer.Stop();

            var success = await ProcessUpdates();
            // Some stuff depending on whether ProcessUpdates succeeded
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception
        }
        finally
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private async Task<SomeSettingsStruct> ProcessUpdates()
    {
        try
        {
            string json = await _client.GetStringAsync($"http://{_iotIPaddress}/di_value/slot_0"); //Exception is thrown on this line

            var resultdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeSettingsStruct>(json);

            return resultdata;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log the exception
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And most of the time this works fine. But once in a while the connection will lag (the device is connected trough wifi) and GetStringAsync throws out some expected exceptions (hehe) but sometimes this seems to cause the code to block for a long time. This could indicate network problems that last longer then a couple of minutes but people on-site don't believe this to be the case. Therefore the problem must sit in the code somewhere.

Especially this async callback method doesn't sit right by me, the timer calls it's callback on a different thread anyway, so what happens with the async/await stuff in the callback? Are those called on the timer thread or are they their own Task?
Can this cause race conditions, doing weird stuff with HttpClient?

This is the exception I'd get in our logs:

> A task was canceled at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Example.Namespace.Class.d__13.MoveNext() in C:\dev\Project\Example\Namespace\Class.cs:line 103

And since we also log FirstChanceExceptions I see this coming up often before that happens:

> Exception occured: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request 123.456.789.0:80

Comment: Why is `private async SomeSettingsStruct ProcessUpdates()` not like  `private async Task<SomeSettingsStruct> ProcessUpdates()`? Do you have a custom awaiter in your "struct"?

Comment: @JoePhillips `OnTimer` is an event handler, so `async void` is fine, here.

Comment: @Fildor it's not `async void`, it's `async Something`. That's invalid syntax.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `private async void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

Comment: The event handler is still an `async void` which means nothing awaits for it to complete. If the application terminates, it will still be running and its thread will be aborted.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you meant `private async SomeSettingsStruct ProcessUpdates()` - which I agree is wrong.

Comment: @Fildor oops, mixed up the comments. ` async SomeSettingsStruct ProcessUpdates` is invalid syntax but I expect it's a typo and really is `async Task<SomeSettingsStruct> ProcessUpdates`

Comment: Depending on *how* you're going to use this class and timer there are number of options here. For example - can you use 'true parallelism' and run each handler on its own thread ? Or it is required that call number 2 waits for call number 1 to complete ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Therefore the problem must sit in the code somewhere.

Not necessarily. I don't think there is anything wrong with your code at all.

`HttpClient` throws a `TaskCanceledException` when a timeout occurs (i.e. when there is no response and it gives up waiting). It's not intuitive, and [people have complained](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20296), but that's the way it is.

People [have found workarounds](https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/) to make it throw a better exception, but I don't think you need to bother with that. The only other time a `TaskCanceledException` is thrown is if you pass a `CancellationToken` and it signals the cancellation. But you aren't passing one, so you can be sure that if it does throw a `TaskCanceledException`, it is because of a timeout.

You could *extend* the timeout ([`_client.Timeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=netframework-4.8)) beyond the default 100 seconds, but if this is over an unreliable wireless connection, then that could do a whole lot of nothing.

My bets are on network problems. You could verify this with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) (verify that the request is sent, but nothing received).